# jQuery Collapsible tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, tabindex

Using jquery.collapsible.js I notice that the tabindex does not change when expanded/closed. I nearly have a solution but would appreciate it if someone could improve on this piece of code as I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
$('.collapsible').each(function() {
 $('.collapsible').on('click',function(e) {
 if($('div').hasClass('collapsible collapse-open')) {
$('.collapsible.collapse-open').attr("tabIndex", 0);
 } else {
$('.collapsible.collapse-close').attr("tabIndex", -1);
}

});

});
```

The problem is the tabindex only changes on the second click and then the 0,-1 order is wrong.

Comment: The problem is the tabindex only changes on the second click and then the 0,-1 order is wrong.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle or a SO snippet showing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ihan for the more efficient script. It is working now I just had to change the default class from 'collapse-open' to 'collapse-close'.

```
$(".collapsible").on('click', function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var tabIndex = self.hasClass("collapse-close") ? 0 : -1;
    self.attr("tabIndex", tabIndex); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a better way, and your solution already works, you could simplify it with this. You don't need to loop through each `.collapsible` with the `each` function just to add the `click` event handler.

```
$(".collapsible").on('click', function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var tabIndex = self.hasClass("collapse-open") ? 0 : -1;
    self.attr("tabIndex", tabIndex); 
});
```

This will select any element with the class `collapsible`, bind the click event, and then check if that element has the `collapse-open` class to determine which tab index to apply.

Comment: Thanks Ihan that is much cleaner, however, I am still having a problem with the tabindex only changes on the second click and then the 0,-1 order is wrong  I have added the HTML section to the question. To clarify this is when the tree section is first opened.

Comment: Added HTML <div tabindex="-1" class="collapsible" id="section06" role="treeitem" data-id="06" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsible-06" aria-label="my label"><p><strong>My Label</strong></p></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-container" id="collapsible-06" aria-hidden="true">
      <p>collapse content </p>
                    </div>

Comment: I can see why. At the default there is no class 'collapse-open'. I need to rethink

Comment: what if instead of checking for `collapse-open`, you just check for not having `collapse-close`? Then you could set it to 0 even if it doesn't have `collapse-open`, as long as it doesn't have `collapse-close`? Just a thought.